# How to you control which test case gets run first?

Tags: unit-testing, tdd, xcode6, xctest

I have created a few XCTestCase and I would like them to run in a specific order.  How to you control which test case gets run first?

Comment: Tests should stand on their own, it shouldn't matter what order they are run in.

Answer (score 1):

Unit tests should have ability to run in any order, and be separated from results of any other tests. If they can't - this is already integration, not unit tests.

XCTest don't have any features for integration tests. Consider to use something like [kif-framework](https://github.com/kif-framework/KIF) or  switch to handwritten testing.